# Как бороться с запретом программного нажатия на элемент?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Возникла такая проблема. На сайте есть уведомления, по нажатию мышки на котором -- открывается новое окно. Но в js написано:

> data.click = false;

Из-за этого, как я понимаю, не выходит нажать на это уведомление используя js. 
Знает кто-то как с этим бороться?

Comment: Просто все браузеры уже давно запрещают всплывающие окошки, всплытие которых инициировано программно. Да, браузер следит за тем, кто нажимает кнопки. Глупый пользователь или хитрожопый жаваскрипт. Попросите пользователя включить разрешение на всплытие всякого.

Comment: Уведомления представляют собой обычные, джаваскрипт-сформированные блоки. На это тоже распространяется всё вышеизложенное?
З.Ы, При нажатии мышкой -- уведомления открываются нормально

Comment: Блоки (div?) вроде должны открываться. Может в них iframe и из-за него не открывается? Про iframe не помню. Да и про блоки тоже. Но раз они вплывают там и тут на разных сайтах, то блоки скорее всего можно.

Comment: Да, блоки (div).